# how can i use file.get(char ) after getline()?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, seekg

Here is my code, I don't understand why the `get(char)` give me the wrong result !

```cpp
ifstream uploadFile("upload.txt");
string line;
getline(uploadFile,line);
getline(uploadFile,line);
uploadFile.seekg(3,ios::cur);
char lettre;
uploadFile.get(lettre);
cout << "we get the letter : " << lettre << endl;
```

i was expected that the output will be:

> d

(because the first `getline` store the `"0 TS1"` in `line`, then the second `getline` store `"paris"` in `line`, then we move the pointer 3 chars ahead so it will be between the `"n"` and the `"d"` of `london`).

but I actually have:

> m

btw here is my file:

```
0 TS1  
paris  
london  
amsterdam      

1 TC2  
xxxxx  
yyyyy  
zzzzz
```

I'm using codeblocks on Windows 10, and I created my file with Notepad on Windows.

Comment: ***codeblocks on windows 10*** Probably means some version of `mingw`.

Comment: Most likely, the file you read is not the file you think you read. Print the first two lines, confirm that they are as expected.

Comment: The `ifstream` is likely buffering data, the `getline()` calls are reading more than they return, so the file pointer is farther into the file than you are expecting. Check with `tellg()` before calling `seekg()` to confirm. Try using `uploadFile.ignore(3)` instead of `uploadFile.seekg(3,ios::cur)`

Comment: what ! i tried with uploadFile.ignore(3) and it works !! but i don't understand why